# Reading a file path without knowing the file Directory or parent file

Tags: java, string, directory, filenames

I’m writing a java program that needs to find a file directory only having the file name. For example, I know the file is called “Img_123.png” but I do not know it’s file directory, file name, or file path. I need to know the entire file name in as a string(in order to draw it using Canvas).

Answer (score 0):

Provided root folder to start your search and the max allowed depth, this should return list of all files that match the filename:

```
List<File> findFileByName(Path start, String fileName, int maxDepth) throws IOException {
  final Stream<Path> files = Files.find(start, maxDepth, (path, attribute) -> { 
    return path.endsWith(fileName);
  });
  return files
    .map(path -> path.toFile())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

`(path, attribute) -> { //any code }` that you're confused about is a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) an [anonymous function](https://hashnode.com/post/anonymous-functions-in-java-explained-cj1opkbj8000sml53bsq6r6cj). It's type is`BiPredicate<Path,BasicFileAttributes>` which means it should return a Boolean based on some evaluation of the path and attributes for the file being processed.

Comment: Where are `path` and `attribute` defined?

Comment: Those are Path and BasicInfoAttribute types, from the file you are currently processing. They are not local variables but are assigned automatically in lambda.

Check documentation for Files.find

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-

and for BiPredicate<T, U>

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html

Comment: What integers are recommended maxDepth for use of scanning the entire C drive for a specific file folder

Comment: If you want to be sure that everything is scanned, use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` constant.

Comment: @IvanSidenko If my answer has helped you, please mark it as answer

Comment: @nemanja228 For whatever reason, the File<File> part of the code keeps throwing an error. *remove argument type*